# ¿Cómo puedo insertar el widget de revolvermaps en React?

Tags: reactjs

Quiero insertar un widget del planeta girando ([revolvermaps](https://www.revolvermaps.com/)) en React. He insertado el script que me proporciona la página pero no se muestra:

```html
<div style={{textAlign: "center" }}>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//rf.revolvermaps.com/0/0/6.js?i=5s8wq4wsqcz&amp;m=7&amp;c=e63100&amp;cr1=ffffff&amp;f=arial&amp;l=0&amp;bv=90&amp;lx=-420&amp;ly=420&amp;hi=20&amp;he=7&amp;hc=a8ddff&amp;rs=80" async="async"></script>
</div>
```

Lo curioso es que lo copié en Codepen y ahí sí se muestra ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mariley/pen/EodZxV)).
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esto me Funciono:

```html
<div id="revolvermap" align="center"  className="wcustomhtml">
    <div className="ab">
        <div className="abc">
            <iframe className="adc" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" width="50%" height="50%" src="//rf.revolvermaps.com/w/6/a/a2.php?i=5dv1qe7od2v&amp;m=7&amp;c=e63100&amp;cr1=ffffff&amp;f=arial&amp;l=0&amp;bv=90&amp;lx=-400&amp;ly=400&amp;hi=20&amp;he=7&amp;hc=a8ddff&amp;rs=80"></iframe>
         </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//rf.revolvermaps.com/0/0/6.js?i=5dv1qe7od2v&amp;m=7&amp;c=e63100&amp;cr1=ffffff&amp;f=arial&amp;l=0&amp;bv=90&amp;lx=-400&amp;ly=400&amp;hi=20&amp;he=7&amp;hc=a8ddff&amp;rs=80" async="async"></script>
</div>
```